# Python SQL - Inserting values into identifiable columns from List

Tags: python, sql, for-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, identifier

I have a list: reward_coupons, which is a list that can range in length from 1- 9 and contain reward IDs.

I have a table (which I call from an identifier table name) which contains 9 columns named reward_id_01,reward_id_02...reward_id_09.

In my reward_coupons list, customers can recieve 1 up to 9 rewards, so I would like to create a loop which inserts the values I have in my list(in order) to the table (identifier ($table_name))

```
for i in range(len(reward_coupons)):
    cs.execute("""SET reward_id_name =(SELECT 'reward_id_0');""")
    cs.execute("""SET column_number = (%s)""",(str(i+1)))
    cs.execute("""SET Column_Name = (SELECT concat($reward_id_name,$column_number))""")
    get_column_name = (cs.execute("SELECT $Column_name;").fetch_pandas_all())
    cs.execute("""UPDATE identifier ($table_name) SET (%s) = (%s)""",(get_column_name.astype(str),reward_coupons[i]))
```

However I get the below error:

snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (dataframe) is not supported

What would be the best way to insert into these columns from my reward coupon list? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to to this problem.

It seems that because "Column" is not a datatype you cannot pass a variable in using the following syntax:

```
...(%s)""",(get_column_name.astype(str))
```

This passes a literal string where the SQL compilator does not recongize column names as strings.
The code below using % instead of a comma, passes what is in the string and allows the SQL to execute.

```
for i in range(len(reward_coupons)):
    cs.execute("""SET reward_id_name =(SELECT 'reward_id_0');""")
    cs.execute("""SET column_number = (%s)""",(str(i+1)))
    cs.execute("""SET Column_Name = (SELECT concat($reward_id_name,$column_number))""")
    get_column_name = (cs.execute("SELECT $Column_name;").fetch_pandas_all())
    query = """UPDATE identifier ($table_name) SET (%s)"""%(get_column_name.astype(str).iloc[0][0]
    query = query + """ = (%s)"""
    cs.execute(query,reward_coupons[i])
```